# Application declared in AndroidManifest, but android studio says the class is never used and app crashes

Tags: android, android-studio

So this is a new problem for me. I have a class called App in the base of my project. Looks something like this:

```
   // v-- The class name is grey and says its not in used. This started happening suddenly.
class App : Application {
    ...
    Some vital stuff for my app
    ...
}
```

The class is of course declared in the Manifest.

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    ...
```

`Ctrl+click` on `.App` in the manifest opens the correct file like expected. So why doesn't Android Studio say the app class is in use? And why isn't App called when running the app in emulator or a phone?

I have cleaned the project. Rebuilt it a number of times. Cleared Caches and restarted Android Studio. Same problem.

Has this happened to anyone else?

Comment: try to use full path for your App class

Comment: Didn't work either :(